# Resoution 1280x1024 grabbing issue with OpenCV 2.4.2?

Tags: video, opencv, camera, frame, video-capture

I don't know whats wrong with OpenCV 2.4.2 with Visual Stuio 2010. I am trying to grab Camera frame that has 1280x1024 resolution. But OpenCV 2.4.2 always grab only 640x480 resolution. Why ? 
On the other hand, OpenCV 1.1pre working fine. What to do in this kind of issue ? I do not want 1.1pre, kindly give me the solution. Thanks.

These subrotinues I am using.

```
CvCapture* WebCAMinit = cvCaptureFromCAM(arg);
IplImage* imageRGB = cvQueryFrame(WebCAMinit);
```

Comment: I have also tried the sample program "starter_video.cpp", same result I got 640x480 pixels. But in OpenCV 1.1 gives full 1280x1024 resolution. I think something wrong with built-in libs or dll files of OpenCV 2.4.2. Am I right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with cvSetCaptureProperty. 
set the original resolution of camera by cvSetCaptureProperty.